# HTTP and HTTPS version of a same page render differently

Tags: javascript, http, https, rendering

Here are the links to the page in question:

- [http version](http://www.eyeviewdigital.com/blog/eyeview-launches-addressable-tv-ads-with-cablevision-dish-programmatic-tv-w-clypd-and-wideorbit/)
- [https version](https://www.eyeviewdigital.com/blog/eyeview-launches-addressable-tv-ads-with-cablevision-dish-programmatic-tv-w-clypd-and-wideorbit/)

The https version of the page doesn't render the video embedded on the top of the article. I inspected the source code and found that HTTPs is missing an entire block of code, as you can see in the images below:

[image: Image #1]

[image: Image #2]

I wonder how this happens? Isn't http(s) just the protocol to communicate with the server? Why do I get different code by using different protocols?

Comment: You're asking this as a consumer of the page, not as the producer, right?  Presumably the creators of the page can output whatever they want for different protocols.

Comment: `mixed content` on the https version would be a problem

Comment: Not only can whatever is listening to those request return different content for different protocols, there is nothing that says they have to be related in the slightest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Chrome Developer Toolkit:

The page at 'https://www.eyeviewdigital.com/blog/eyeview-launches-addressable-tv-ads-with-cablevision-dish-programmatic-tv-w-clypd-and-wideorbit/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://pshared.5min.com/Scripts/PlayerSeed.js?sid=281&width=480&height=401&playList=519141523'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

You typically need to load your content in either http or https. Mixing them together results in the error above.

On line 252 replace

http://pshared.5min.com/Scripts/PlayerSeed.js?sid=281&width=480&height=401&playList=519141523

with

https://delivery.vidible.tv/aol?sid=281&width=480&height=401&playList=519141523.js

Long story short the content was never loaded so the page looked different.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. I saw a lot of mixed content pages before, and the insecure content still loads correctly, it's just the green lock at the URL bar is grayed out (Chrome). Any idea why in some cases the insecure script cannot be loaded? When you said "the request is blocked", you mean blocked by the browser, or the server?

Comment: This page gives a description on why this happens:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?p=unauthenticated&visit_id=1-636238913046750813-1721813068&rd=1

Answer (score 0):

You're right that there should be no difference based on http/https as it is just the transport layer.  There must be something in the server's code that is producing the html, that behaves differently based on the url used to make the request.  I suggest you provide information on the web server code to help analyse the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused because you're loading elements from insecure sources. Google Chrome for example, loading an image over http when your page is loaded over https can result in the image not loading at all. This is all for security purposes, of course. Just go through all of your code and make sure all sources are accessed through secure https so that they load in properly.